# SP 2010 - Creating a Daily task to do list

Tags: 2010, list, tasks

I'm looking to create a daily to do list, simple enough. However I want to set it so that it will autopopulate with the same few tasks every day at a certain time (say 8am)

Is there a workflow or something I can set up to allow this list to auto populate? My Company doesn't allow us to edit HTML, use SP Designer, Edit JavaScript or use InfoPath/Outlook.

Thanks

Comment: Create Timer job, or workflow using visual studio